# why is it uploading image when it shouldn't do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem where if the file extension is incorrect, it displays an alert. This works fines but the problem is that it shouldn't upload the file. Why is it uploading the file because in the function below I have stated that if imageValidation is passed, then go onto the 'startUploadImage()' function to start uploading:

```
function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
      if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
          return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

Below is the imageValidation() code where it checks for file extension:

```
function imageValidation(imageuploadform) {

    var val = $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif':
        case 'jpg': 
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'pjpeg':
        case 'png':
             return true;

        case '':
            $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
                     alert("To upload an image, please select an Image File");
            return false;

        default:
             alert("To upload an image, please select a valild file extension.");
             return false;

    }

    return false;

}
```

I don't know if you need to see the startImageUpload function but if you do then this is also below:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

      return true;
}
```

Code showing the form:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" +

    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label>" +

    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 

    "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" +

    "<input type='button' name='cancelImageBtn' class='cancelimage' value='Cancel' /></label>" + 
    "</p></form>");
```

Comment: Does it actually display the alert box and then uploads the image anyway?

Comment: yes it does, I have a php code on another page which does all the uploading and it does display the alert box when I click on the alert box. The problem is that it alerts me when file extension is incorrect but it still uploads the image file

Comment: okay, that is highly mysterious. The alert box is only displayed when you return false from the function, and when the function returns false the sertImageUpload() function is not called by that code. Are you sure there is nothing else happening than the code you have posted here?

Comment: I will post the code for the form, give me 5 mins. But like I said when the user clicks on the Upload button, if file extension is incorrect then it displays the alert but then at the top I see the browser loading which makes me think it is still uploading the file

Comment: Code showing form is posted at the bottom of my question

Comment: Ok what is happening is that when I click on the 'Upload' button and imageValidation isn't passed, it displays an alert and then when I click on 'OK' in the alert, then it does the uploading, do you know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your forms onsubmit event. You it should look like this:

```
onsubmit="return imageClickHandler(this);"
```

Note the *return*. If that isn't there, then the result of the imagehandler function is not returned, and the submit event is not cancelled.

Also, actually using single qoutes (') on attributes is not really valid html. You should probably switch them to double qoutes, and then use single qoutes as the terminators for the javascript strings. Like this:

```
var $fileImage = $('<form action="imageupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="return imageClickHandler(this);" class="imageuploadform" >' +  
    'Image File: <input name="fileImage" type="file" class="fileImage" /></label><br/><label>' +
    '<input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label>' +
    '</p><p class="imagef1_cancel" align="center"><label>' +
    '<input type="button" name="cancelImageBtn" class="cancelimage" value="Cancel" /></label>' + 
    '</p></form>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your targetting imageuploadform incorrectly

it should be $("#imageuploadform") if it is the id or $(".imageuploadform") if it is a class

But it seems there may be even more wrong with the coe as well

Comment: imageuploadform is the class for the form. <form class='imageuploadform'>

Comment: To target the classes then you will need to use $(".imageuploadform")

Comment: If you look at last function, it contains this line of code: sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;. Does that need to change to sourceImageForm = $(.imageuploadform);? (sourseImageForm is simply just a variable) Also does function startImageUpload(imageuploadform) nned to change to function startImageUpload(.imageuploadform)?